# close approximation of divergent integral

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I want to calculate the integration of this function:

$$ \int_{-\infty }^\infty { 1\over \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2}} dy $$ where $ a $ and $ b $ are the constants.  The integral comes out to be $$ \ln \left ( \left | \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} + y -b \right | \right ) + C $$  Which is divergent in nature over the limits. I have following questions:

1. Is there any other way to deal with such integrals?

   2. Is there any way to find any approximate function of this which does not have this divergence issue?

I am quite new to this stuff, so sorry for any mistakes in this post. thanks for any help in advance.

The above question is already answered by Dr. MV, i have a query while following the same rule in second half of my equation : 
$$ \int_{-\infty }^\infty { y\over \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2}} dy $$ the integral of this comes out to be 
$$ \ln \left ( \left | \sqrt{(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} + y -b \right | \right ) + \sqrt {(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2} + C $$

this function still remains divergent. is there any way to deal with this

thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral of interest fails to exist even as a [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation).  To see this, we write

$$\begin{align}
\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty }^\infty { 1\over \sqrt{(x-a)^2 - (y-b)^2}} dy\right)&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-L}^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}}\,dy\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty} \left. \left(\log\left((y-b)+\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2}\right)\right)\right|_{-L}^L\\\\
&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\log\left(\frac{(L-b)+\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(L-b)^2}}{-(L+b)+\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(L+b)^2}}\right)\\\\
&= \infty
\end{align}$$

If we wish to analyze the behavior of the integral before passing to the limit, we can proceed as follows.

$$\begin{align}
\log\left(\frac{(L-b)+\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(L-b)^2}}{-(L+b)+\sqrt{(x-a)^2+(L+b)^2}}\right)&=\log\left(\frac{(L-b)\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x-a}{L-b}\right)^2}+1\right)}{(L+b)\left(\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x-a}{L+b}\right)^2}-1\right)}\right)\\\\
&\sim 2\log(L)
\end{align}$$

Comment: @thanks Dr. MV . i have a little bit doubt as mentioned in edited part of question . can you please put some light on that.

Comment: thanks! this time i cannot figure out how its close to 2log(L). if very much silly question then  sorry

Comment: @Vicky Remember that we are viewing $L$ as "large."  So, using the Taylor expansion, we have $$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x-a}{L+b}\right)^2}-1=\frac12 \left(\frac{x-a}{L+b}\right)^2+O\left(\left(\frac{x-a}{L+b}\right)^4\right)$$